# run two commands one after another in node js using only one child process

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js. Please forgive me if I didn't use proper terminologies in node js.

Question: I want to run two commands in command prompt. when I run first command(which is a bat file) it sets up lot of env variables and navigates to an location(i.e. C:\abc) so that I can run my second command in the same context.

I tried to do the above in nodejs. But, I couldn't achive this. Below is the code snippet that I tried

```
const child = require("child_process").execSync;
const process = child(configLoc + "\\abc.bat")
process = child("command2")
if (process.status !== 0) {
  throw new Error(process.stderr.toString());
}
if(process.stderr) {
  if (typeof process.stderr === 'string') process.stderr = new Error(process.error);
   throw process.stderr;
}
return process.stdout.toString();
```

My problem is both the commands are running as a different instances. I want them to run one after another. run command1 and later command2 in the same instance not in different instance. so that my second command executes fine otherwise second command will fail.

I tried to combine the two commands using && but no success. Please help me achieving this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting when doing: `&&` which is the best solution? Because that should work. Is `abc.bat` exiting successfully?

Comment: As you stated, you said that you are running the command in different instances? if so maybe you can try using some kind of Pub/Sub services?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande If I use && bat file is executing and the second command is not executing